# virtual keyboard enter key code

Tags: javascript, html, virtual-keyboard

I am trying to make a virtual keyboard using html and javascript. I want to append the characters to a div (div1) which already has some content(using div1.textContent+=thenewcharacter).
While this works perfectly for backspace,letters and numbers,it doesn't seem to work for enter key...I have added an event listener for a "click" on the enter key.

I have tried all these..

```
function entr(){
    //div1.textContent+="\n";
    //var a=div1.innerHTML="<br>";
    //div1.innerHTML+="<br>";
    //div1.textContent=div1.textContent+a;
    //div1.appendChild(div1.innerHTML="<br>");
    //}
    //div1.appendChild("<br>");
}
```

inner html,appendChild..\n,
,.textContent...none of it seems to work! I'd like to know if there is another way to do this without changing much of the code.

Thanks:)

Comment: I have tried: function entr(){
 //div1.textContent+="\n";
 //var a=div1.innerHTML="<br>";
 //div1.innerHTML+="<br>";
 //div1.textContent=div1.textContent+a;
 //div1.appendChild(div1.innerHTML="<br>");
    //}
 //div1.appendChild("<br>");
}

Comment: The following could be modified and used: var onclick = function(){
    var e = $.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 13; // Character 'A'
    $(this).trigger(e);
};

Comment: In the context of a div you may find that one <br> isn't enough - a lot of divs end with <br></div> anyway without showing an extra line. Try adding <br><br> ...

Comment: I believe the `<br>` is being stripped out when you use `textContent` after `innerHTML`. It might be better to only use `innerHTML` in that code.